# How to get HH:MM:SS difference using milliseconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-native, momentjs

I have two times like one is 145:02:31 and another one is 01:00:00 and I want to calculate the difference between these two times like 144:02:31 but right now I am getting 13:02:31 which is wrong.

Please help me thank you.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: what will be the format for the minutes and seconds? 60 ?

Comment: var difference1 = moment
        .utc(
          moment(milliseconds).diff(
            moment(milliseconds)
          )
        )
        .format("HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 1):

It's a little crude with the formatting but works just the way you need.

```js
function format_ms(time_ms) {
  let hours = 0;
  let minutes = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  
  hours = parseInt(time_ms / 3600000).toString();

  time_ms %= 3600000;
  
  minutes = parseInt(time_ms / 60000).toString();
  
  time_ms %= 60000;
  
  seconds = parseInt(time_ms / 1000).toString();
  
  return hours + ":" + minutes.padStart(2, '0') + ":" + seconds.padStart(2, '0');
}


let start = moment.duration('145:02:31');
let end = moment.duration('1:00:00');
let delta_ms = start - end; // in ms

console.log(format_ms(delta_ms));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

It will give you the time difference in hours.

Answer (score 0):

Here a try without any external lib. 
steps ->
 1. convert the `timestamp` in `seconds` 
 2. calculate diff
 3. revert second into desired format

```
function diff(a, b){
  const getSec = val => {
    const arr = val.split(':')
    return Number(arr[2]) + Number(arr[1])*60 + Number(arr[0])*3600
   }
  const diff =  getSec(a) - getSec(b)

  const h = parseInt(diff/3600)
  const m = parseInt((diff - h*3600)/60)
  const s = diff%60

  return`${h}:${m}:${s}`
}

diff("145:02:31", "01:00:00" ) //"144:2:31"
```

Comment: `Number(arr[1])*60` is redundant, `arr[1] * 60` is sufficient, same for `arr[0]`.

Comment: actually, `val` is string and `arr` becomes array of string. At the time `addition` to calculate `seconds` it `concats` as the strings instead adding the as numbers

Comment: Then `(arr[1])*60)` is less to type. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Convert time in format H:mm:ss to seconds
function hrsToSecs(hrs) {
  var b = hrs.split(':');
  return b[0]*3600 + b[1]*60 + +b[2];
}

// Convert seconds to time in format H:mm:ss
function secsToHrs(secs) {
  var z = n => (n<10? '0':'') + n; 
  return (secs/3600 | 0) + ':' + 
         z(secs%3600/60 | 0) + ':' + 
         z(secs%60);
}

// Get different between times in H:mm:ss format
// Subtract first time from second
function timeDiff(t0, t1) {
  var diff = hrsToSecs(t1) - hrsToSecs(t0);
  return (diff < 0? '-' : '') + secsToHrs(Math.abs(diff));
}

console.log(timeDiff('1:01:01','0:01:00'))
console.log(timeDiff('01:00:00','145:02:31'));
```